# Python list() function update to accept a non-iterable?

Tags: python, language-design

I've been working on a "learning project" which involves several short single-parameter functions, where the parameter might be either a numeric type or a list of numerics.  E.g.,

```
def magnitude_of(v):
    try:
        return math.sqrt(sum([vi**2 for vi in v]))
    except:
        return abs(v)
```

This of course is necessary because if I did this:

```
def magnitude_of(v):
    return math.sqrt(sum([vi**2 for vi in list(v)]))
```

...the code would fail because `list()` only accepts an iterable as an argument.

My question is:  has there ever been consideration given at PSW to letting `list()` work with any argument?  If so, what prevented the change from being implemented?

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing that _could_ be implemented, but hasn't been, because not enough people have asked for it. I look forward to your grassroots campaign ;-)

Comment: What exactly is `v`? In the first code example you're iterating over `v`, which makes `v` appear to be an iterable. However, in the next code example you say you can't use `list(v)` because `v` _isn't_ an iterable.

Comment: One could just wrap it into list before passing into list comprehension. In some cases explicit is better then implicit =)

Comment: You seem to have crammed two completely unrelated functionalities into the same function. Why not write two separate functions, that way you don't have to worry about what `v` is at all.

Comment: @ChristianDean, the parameter v might be either iterable or non-iterable.  This is a low-level piece of a data science project, where the functions/data being analyzed might have only one variable or multiple variables.  COLDSPEED, same response:  flexibility in the upper levels requires flexibility here.

Comment: Use `numpy.linalg.norm` - it works for both use cases out of the box.

Comment: You can just wrap the behaviour you desire in a function and use your function instead of `list`. It will work.

Comment: @EricChiesse, true and I already thought about it, but that just pushes off the not-quite-elegant piece to another level.  My `flex_list(x)` function would be another try-except, returning `list(v)` or `[v]`.

Comment: Worth noting that while `list(v)` will fail if v isn't iterable, `[v]` is perfectly valid to create a single-element list.

Comment: While I'm generally in favor of functions trying to be friendly to callers, when the function requires an iterable, processing a single value is as trivial as wrapping it with `[...]` when calling the function. There's not a lot of value in eliminating those two keystrokes. In this function especially, the result is the same. If you want to streamline the single-item case, you can still do this by checking the length of the iterable and returning `abs(v[0])` in that case. (Also, you can replace `vi**2` with `vi*vi`, which is about ten times faster on my machine...)

Comment: @JDM Once its wrapped in a function you just see it as a blackbox. I see it as a pretty valid solution.

Comment: Alright, alright everyone.... instead of dozens of comments questioning why I'm doing this in the first place and telling me I shouldn't do it....does anyone have an answer to the question I actually asked?  (As I explained already this is a low-level piece of a larger and relatively complicated data science learning project.  If you really really want I can post the whole project to justify my design decision here, but......)

Comment: If something were to be changed in the language, I'd rather see atomic values becoming iterable, yielding themselves, instead of changing `list()` and other constructors to accept both iterables and single values.

Comment: Why don't you just check the type of the argument passed in to see if it's a list, as opposed to a try catch?

Comment: @EnricoBorba, I'm following the pythonic idiom of "Ask forgiveness rather than permission."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just create my own list function and use it for this particular purpose.

Ex:

```
def mlist(v):
    try:
        return list(v)
    except(TypeError):
        return [v]
```

Now you use `mlist` instead of `list`

```
l1 = mlist(1)
l2 = mlist([1])
```

Both will give `[1]` as the result

Comment: I changed. I like to assign to a variable for debugging purposes. But in this case it's not really necessary.

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question I asked, but I'm good with the DIY approach to getting around a minor limitation of the language.

Comment: If you don't actually need a list, but just need something you can iterate over, you could use `iter()` here instead of `list()`. This will avoid copying the list if one has been passed in.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on whether this has come up at PSW, but I generally prefer using a ternary here instead of try... catch
e.g.

```
def magnitude_of(v):
    return math.sqrt(sum([vi*vi for vi in (v if isinstance(v,list) else [v])]))
```

Granted, as others have mentioned it would probably be best if the function simply requires a list to be passed